# how to store 'wav' audio file in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I tried the below query for storing wav audio file into mySQL.

```
update files set sample=
load_file('C:\Users\VIGNESH\Desktop\project\VRS\test2.wav') 
where number=789;
```

files is my table name,sample is my column name of datatype `mediumblob` and number is an another column.

when i executed the above query,it is showing as

```
'query ok,0 rows affected'
```

the audio file is not getting stored into the database.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting NULL in there, run these checks:

- file exists ( :) ) and is on the host server (aka: no referencing from one server to your local machine)
- everyone has reading permissions for the file
- the file has to be shorter than max_allowed_packet
- if you have this variable secure_file_priv pointing to some directory, than the file has to be put in that one

source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file